# Pulling data into d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3, and with a background in server-side development I find a few things confusing.  I still struggle to understand how to bring data in from outside sources.  In my case, I can see the benefit of pulling data from the database on demand and visualizing it, but how does that data get into D3?  I've attempted to pull it in through Ajax, but I haven't found a good D3 v4 demo that covers this.  Are there any?  Do most people write to csv/json/tsv files and import that way?

Answer (score 3):

D3 v4 has [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request) for fetching data using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). `d3-request` has been deprecated as of v5, however, in favor of [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch) which uses the new [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

D3 doesn't rely on any special data structures, so these are really just for convenience. You could also use any library or API for fetching data that you like.

There are code snippets for using both `d3-request` and `d3-fetch` in the documentation for those modules, and if you want to see a more complete example, this [basic bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304) loads data from a TSV to build the bar chart.

There are more examples in the [gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery) as well as many great [tutorials](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Tutorials) in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

So you're correct, most D3 examples use something like `d3.csv` or `d3.json` in the following form:

```
d3.csv("myfile.csv", function(data) {
    d3.select("svg")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .join(data)
      ...
});
```

However this is purely for convenience in the examples. If you know you're data is going to be `JSON` based then you can use `d3.json` to simply call your API.

However, you can equally do this with regular API requests. Here is an example using the new fetch API provided in vanilla JavaScript:

```
const render = (data) => {
    d3.select("svg")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .join(data)
      ...
};

const request = new Request("/myAPI/myRoute/getAllCircles");
fetch(request)
    .then((response) => response.json()) // Convert to JSON format
    .then((jsonData) => {  render(jsonData); });
```